# html how to refer to the file in input tag

Tags: jquery, html

suppose I have a simple form with a `<input type="file">` tag, what i want to do is, once the user select a file, I'd like to display that file(it is an img) on the same page for viewing. better user experience.

tried to set the value based on onChange event, then realized this doesn't work.

any thoughts?

Comment: How about dropping some code?

Answer (score 3):

You can't access the client's filesystem from the browser sandbox. It goes against the browser's security model. You'll just have to wait for the user to upload the file before you can display it.

Comment: That's a neat trick but basically a variation on what I said which is that the file must be uploaded to a server before it can be displayed on the page. Can you cite an example of a website that uses this technique?

Comment: See for example Contacts in Gmail. When you select image it is displayed immediately. You can find many other examples. Sorry can't recall any other at the moment.

Comment: @Arman P. Thanks for the example. It's a clever workaround. I'm going to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to catch onChange event and upload the file using Ajax (asynchronously).

**Hint**: Submit form on onChange event and send the post data to server-side script.

This technology is used by many websites, though it will be slow if connection of client is slow and the file is big. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You **do not** need to upload the image before you can display it. Here's a JQuery snippet that will to the trick:

```
$('input:file').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];  
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = (function(event) { 
    $('#previewImage').attr('src',event.target.result); 
    });  
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);   
});
```